# How to generate node.bcrypt.js equivalent encrypted password in grails

Tags: node.js, grails, grails-plugin, bcrypt

This is common login feature.I am using grails bcrypt 1.0 to generate encrypted password in one application, but another application using node.bcrypt.js. These both are not generating the same encrypted password.  Please help me to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: that's not necessarily a problem - if you hash a password twice with bcrypt you'll always get a different hash, but they're equivalent. when you verify the cleartext password against either hash they'll both work

Comment: I will encrypt password using grails app and other application uses node.bcrypt.js to verify the password. I am not hashing the password twice

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. If you hash the password twice in Grails and twice in node, you'll get 4 different hashes. But the two in Grails will be equivalent because they'll both compare correctly with a valid cleartext password, and the two in node will be equivalent too. My point was that they might all be equivalent, or there might be a configuration difference that needs to be addressed. But getting a different hash in Grails and node is not necessarily a problem

Comment: It is working now. In mongo application they are initially hashing with SHA256.js. So when i did same in my application its working.